# How to use LOG4NET for specific events

Tags: c#, log4net

Hi just learning Log4net and i am stuck at something

I am using `Info(...)` for write log files, but I also need to use `Info(...)` for email in specific events.

So one call to `Info(...)` writes to the log and and sends an email.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to accomplish this would be to [add a filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#filters) to your SMTP appender: a [StringMatchFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter.html) is probably your best bet.

There is an example of using a StringMatchFilter with an SMTPAppender at http://maonet.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/use-log4net-filter-to-dispatch-email-notification-based-on-string-match

The author notes:

- filter type set to log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter
- each filter section can only have one stringToMatch element
- end with a “log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter” filter to switch from the default “accept all unless instructed otherwise” filtering behavior to a “deny all unless instructed otherwise” behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra logger for your specific logger in you log4net config:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="DefaultAppender" type="...">
    ...
  </appender>
  <appender name="MailAppender" type="...">
    ...
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="DefaultAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger name="MyLoggerNameMail">
    <level value="INFO" />
   <appender-ref ref="MailAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```